# Passport: Multiple 3rd Party Authorizations Without Local User?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, google-oauth, passport.js

It it possible to have a user be associated with multiple 3rd party accounts (in my case, Google and Facebook) but not with a local user account using Passport for Express/Node? In other words, I'd like to authenticate people based off of their 3rd party accounts, but not force them to create an additional local account just for the sake of unifying the rest of their 3rd party information in one place.

In addition, if they login with Google, it should automatically get their Facebook access information (if this has already been previously associated with that Google account), and vice versa.